# Nested Cross Validation with Optuna

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to perform nested cross validation using Optuna. I am wondering what your take is on my solution. Would one implement it like this or am I making some fundamental mistakes? In particular with the branching strategy and mixing `trial.suggest_categorical` and `OptunaSearchCV`

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from optuna.integration import OptunaSearchCV
import optuna
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from optuna.distributions import CategoricalDistribution, FloatDistribution, IntDistribution

pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ("scaling", "passthrough"),
        ("estimator", DecisionTreeClassifier()),
    ]
)
    
    
class OptunaNestedCV:
    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.data = data
        self.x = self.data.data
        self.y = self.data.target

    def __call__(self, trial, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
        classifier_name = trial.suggest_categorical(
            "classifier", ["SVC", "RandomForest"]
        )
        if classifier_name == "SVC":
            param_distributions = {
                "scaling": optuna.distributions.CategoricalDistribution(
                    [MinMaxScaler(), StandardScaler()]
                ),
                "estimator__C": optuna.distributions.FloatDistribution(
                    1e-10, 1e10, log=True
                ),
                "estimator__degree": optuna.distributions.IntDistribution(1, 5),
            }
            estimator = pipe.set_params(estimator=SVC(gamma="auto"))
            classifier_obj = OptunaSearchCV(
                estimator=estimator,
                param_distributions=param_distributions,
                cv=2,
                n_jobs=-1,
            )
        else:
            estimator = pipe.set_params(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10))
            param_distributions = {
                "scaling": optuna.distributions.CategoricalDistribution(
                    [MinMaxScaler(), StandardScaler()]
                ),
                "estimator__max_depth": optuna.distributions.IntDistribution(1, 5),
            }
            classifier_obj = OptunaSearchCV(
                estimator=estimator,
                param_distributions=param_distributions,
                cv=2,
                n_jobs=-1,
            )

        score = cross_val_score(classifier_obj, self.x, self.y, n_jobs=1, cv=3)
        accuracy = score.mean()
        return accuracy
    
class OptunaCV:
    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.data = data
        self.x = self.data.data
        self.y = self.data.target

    def __call__(self, trial, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
        classifier_name = trial.suggest_categorical(
            "classifier", ["SVC", "RandomForest"]
        )
        if classifier_name == "SVC":
            param_distributions = {
                "scaling": optuna.distributions.CategoricalDistribution(
                    [MinMaxScaler(), StandardScaler()]
                ),
                "estimator__C": optuna.distributions.FloatDistribution(
                    1e-10, 1e10, log=True
                ),
                "estimator__degree": optuna.distributions.IntDistribution(1, 5),
            }
            estimator = pipe.set_params(estimator=SVC(gamma="auto"))
            classifier_obj = OptunaSearchCV(
                estimator=estimator,
                param_distributions=param_distributions,
                cv=2,
                n_jobs=-1,
            )
        else:
            estimator = pipe.set_params(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10))
            param_distributions = {
                "scaling": optuna.distributions.CategoricalDistribution(
                    [MinMaxScaler(), StandardScaler()]
                ),
                "estimator__max_depth": optuna.distributions.IntDistribution(1, 5),
            }
            classifier_obj = OptunaSearchCV(
                estimator=estimator,
                param_distributions=param_distributions,
                cv=2,
                n_jobs=-1,
            )
        classifier_obj.fit(self.x, self.y)
        score = classifier_obj.best_score_
        trial.set_user_attr("model", classifier_obj.best_estimator_)
        return score


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #load data
    iris = load_iris()
    
    # Get Performance of model
    objective = OptunaNestedCV(iris)
    study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=3)
    print(study.best_value)
    
    # Get eventual model
    study2 = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
    study2.optimize(OptunaCV(iris), n_trials=3)
    print(study2.best_trial.user_attrs)
```